# How to create another AMI on the same EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I do the following actions on AWS EC2:

1. Start one EBS-backed EC2 instance i-1
2. Customize it and create one AMI, let's say it AMI-1
3. After i do further changes to the i-1 instance, i create a new AMI on the instance again
4. I hop i would get two images as AMI-1 and AMI-2 now.
5. But it seems only AMI-2 was created, the original AMI-1 disappear now. And the snapshot belong to AMI-1 still exists. It's strange.

Basically i want to know:

1. So is it the normal behavior for customized AMI on EC2?
2. If any way to let me create multiple AMIs on the same instance?
3. After the AMI-2 is created, the running instances based on AMI-1
   whether be influenced?

Thanks in advance. I could not get it clear from Google or EC2 document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can create multiple AMIs from a single instance.
- AMIs do not disappear unless you explicitly deregister them.
- If you deregister an AMI, it does not affect any running instances that were started from that AMI.

Comment: @ Eric, thanks. I confirmed that there are two AMIs on EC2 now. BTW, on AWS Console, there is only button "De-Register" for AMI, does it do the DELETE action to AMI?

Comment: deregister removes the entry in the list of usable AMIs.  It does not delete the EBS snapshot that was used for that AMI.  In fact, you could register a new AMI using the same snapshot.  I'll change my answer above so that it correctly reads "deregister" instead of the slightly misleading "delete".

Comment: @EricHammond just a minor comment - you can't register a Windows AMI against an existing Snapshot, only Linux.

Comment: @Grace as an alternative to creating lots of AMIs, why not just create snapshots of your custom configuration, start a generic instance from a vanilla AMI, and swap the storage?

Comment: @Jonners: Thanks for the clarification. I know nothing about Windows.